# Mongoose: Find, modify, save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongoose `User` model:

```
var User = mongoose.model('Users',
    mongoose.Schema({
        username: 'string',
        password: 'string',
        rights: 'string'
    })
);
```

I want to find one instance of the `User` model, modify it's properties, and save the changes. This is what I have tried (it's wrong!):

```
User.find({username: oldUsername}, function (err, user) {
    user.username = newUser.username;
    user.password = newUser.password;
    user.rights = newUser.rights;

    user.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```

What is the syntax to find, modify and save an instance of the `User` model?

Comment: I would suggest trying the User.findOne() method instead of User.find()

Comment: @sethetter you should have made this an answer because it's the most correct

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Why not use [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-update)? After all you're not using the found user for anything else than to update it's properties:

```
User.update({username: oldUsername}, {
    username: newUser.username, 
    password: newUser.password, 
    rights: newUser.rights
}, function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
   //handle it
})
```

Comment: Yes, but be awarded of this "Model.update is sending the command directly to MongoDB - documents are not returned - so there's nothing to run validation on" - Aaron Heckmann https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/635

Comment: Please note that the Model.update does not pass the validation defined in the Schema! See first paragraph on: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 124):

The `user` parameter of your callback is an array with `find`.  Use `findOne` instead of `find` when querying for a single instance.

```
User.findOne({username: oldUsername}, function (err, user) {
    user.username = newUser.username;
    user.password = newUser.password;
    user.rights = newUser.rights;

    user.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @DeLac No, the `save` performs an update operation in this case.

Comment: @DeLac, you may see the duplication key error from saving the User `_id`. In this case, try to update the properties separately or remove `_id` first prior to `save`.

Comment: I can't remove the _id, since other objects refer to it. If I remove it, I guess mongo will choose another _id for it. the update doesn't execute the pre-save functions.  I didn't know that save(), if applied to an existing object, update it. I am not sure how mongo can know when it's an update, and when instead it's an illegal attempt to save a new object with an existing _id

Comment: @DeLac Mongoose keeps track of that via the [`isNew`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) property on Mongoose document instances.

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT TIP. Sometimes I have to use `.markModified` on the doc before saving. If I didn't, the changes wouldn't be saved to the DB. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#usage-notes

Comment: @jackblank that only applies when modifying Date's with built JavaScript functions. From the doc

"Built-in Date methods are not hooked into the mongoose change tracking logic which in English means that if you use a Date in your document and modify it with a method like setMonth(), mongoose will be unaware of this change and doc.save() will not persist this modification."

Doesn't apply in this particular example

Answer (score 8):

[findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), modify fields & save

```
User.findOne({username: oldUsername})
  .then(user => {
    user.username = newUser.username;
    user.password = newUser.password;
    user.rights = newUser.rights;

    user.markModified('username');
    user.markModified('password');
    user.markModified('rights');

    user.save(err => console.log(err));
});
```

OR [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: oldUsername}, {$set: { username: newUser.username, user: newUser.password, user:newUser.rights;}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }
    console.log(doc);
});
```

Also see [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-updateOne)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add something very important. I use JohnnyHK method a lot but I noticed sometimes the changes didn't persist to the database. When I used [`.markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#usage-notes) it worked.

```
User.findOne({username: oldUsername}, function (err, user) {
   user.username = newUser.username;
   user.password = newUser.password;
   user.rights = newUser.rights;

   user.markModified(username)
   user.markModified(password)
   user.markModified(rights)
    user.save(function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error('ERROR!');
    }
});
});
```

> tell mongoose about the change with doc.markModified('pathToYourDate') before saving.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `find`, like I would for any validation you want to do on the client side.

`find` returns an ARRAY of objects

`findOne` returns only an object

Adding `user = user[0]` made the save method work for me.

Here is where you put it.

```
User.find({username: oldUsername}, function (err, user) {
    user = user[0];
    user.username = newUser.username;
    user.password = newUser.password;
    user.rights = newUser.rights;

    user.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Suggesting not to do validation on the server is horrible advice.

Comment: @VtoCorleone the OP's problem is not validation, it's access.Once you have access to the object, you are free to write any logic around it be it validation or modification.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write it a little more cleaner using updateOne & $set, plus async/await.

```
const updateUser = async (newUser) => {
  try {
    await User.updateOne({ username: oldUsername }, {
      $set: {
        username: newUser.username,
        password: newUser.password,
        rights: newUser.rights
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Since you don't need the resulting document, you can just use updateOne instead of findOneAndUpdate.

Here's a good discussion about the difference: [MongoDB 3.2 - Use cases for updateOne over findOneAndUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209434/mongodb-3-2-use-cases-for-updateone-over-findoneandupdate)