# How do I update an object in mongoose methods directly?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How do I update an object in mongoose methods directly?

```
const item = new Schema({
   timeleft: { type: Number, default: 24}
});

ItemSchema.methods.calculateTime = function() { // Done check it one hour
  this.timeleft - 3;
  this.save(); // doesn't work
}


app.get('/getItem/', function(req, res, next) {
    Item.findOne({ name: "name"}, function(err, foundItem) {
      foundItem.calculateTime(); // doesn't work
      res.json(foundItem);
    });
  });
```

I tried this version, doesn't work as well

```
ItemSchema.methods.calculateTime = function() { // Done check it one hour
      this.timeleft - 3;
    }

 app.get('/getItem/', function(req, res, next) {
        Item.findOne({ name: "name"}, function(err, foundItem) {
          foundItem.calculateTime(); // doesn't work
          foundItem.save(function(err, item) {
            res.json(item);
          });
        });
      });
```

How do I update it using mongoose method?

Comment: You can look into this answer : ***http://stackoverflow.com/a/14199703/6269843***

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You checked the object in the DB and it's not updated or what?

Comment: Haha, just realised it's a typo: `this.timeleft - 3;` Of course it doesn't work, it should be `this.timeleft -= 3;` :)